# Why am I getting "ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database"?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

This post was closed just second ago for apparently not being focussed enough. I'm not sure how I could be more specific? I've articulated the context, the code that's erroring and the error statement. What else should I have added? If I'm doing something wrong please leave a comment so I can learn from my mistake.

---

I run this code:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe" -uroot -proot belgarath_test < bets_baseline.sql
```

From this directory:

```
C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\tests\mysql>
```

However, trying to run this line of code:

```
subprocess.run([r'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe', '-uroot', '-proot', 'belgarath_test < bets_baseline.sql'], cwd=r'C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\tests\mysql')
```

Gives this error:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'belgarath_test < bets_baseline.sql'
```

Comment: doesn't `< bets_baseline.sql` in bash mean "pipe this file to the program"?  that means it wouldn't be part of the command line arguments you would need to open the file and pass it to `stdin`

Comment: Does anyone know what was wrong with this post originally?

Comment: the issue with what you had originally is that `... -proot belgarath_test` is the end of the command line arguments, the ` < bets_baseline.sql` part is separate, specifying that the file `bets_baseline.sql` should be piped into the programs stdin.

Comment: Thanks Tadhg. I actually meant what was wrong with the post in regard to it being closed for not being focussed enough. I thought it was a perfectly decent question...

Comment: I don't think this was ever closed? someone might have cast a vote but it is a perfectly good question so that has gone now.

Comment: I had to copy it and repost! Three people apparently voted to close it. Anyway - I got my answer eventually :-). Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `stdin` parameter of `subprocess.run`, for ex:

```
f = open(r"C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\tests\mysql\bets_baseline.sql", "r")
subprocess.run([r'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe',
                '-uroot', '-proot', 'belgarath_test'],
cwd=r'C:\Users\Philip\OneDrive\Betting\Capra\Tennis\polgara\tests\mysql',
stdin = f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction/edit @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! Did generate this warning though: ```ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\Philip\\OneDrive\\Betting\\Capra\\Tennis\\polgara\\tests\\mysql\\bets_baseline.sql' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
  self.import_object()
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback```

Comment: @Jossy That warning is because the file descriptor wasn't close. You can add `f.close()` stmt to close it.